# Terraform - Generate a new map of maps, based on a list of availability zones

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

## Issue

I have a variable that is to be used to generate EC2 launch templates and a variable for a list of availability zones to use. I want the blocks inside the launch template variable to designate details around the implementation, and I want the code to create a launch template PER az (so that I can properly configure the network interface blocks). But I don't want the to require an ec2 configuration block for each AZ (I would like it to be dynamic)

Is there a way to loop over the availability zone list, generate a new map (per map in the launch template configuration) for each AZ and inject the AZ as a key in said map??

## Code Blocks

```
# Some code redacted for brevity
module "env_spinup" {
  availability_zones        = ["az-1", "az-2"]
  ec2_groups = {
    main_ec2_group = {
      instance_count        = 1
      extra_security_groups = []
      root_volume_size      = 200
      extra_tags            = {}
      management_allow_list = {}
    }
  }
}
```

Desired output for the `ec2_groups` argument (parsed into local):

```
ec2_groups = {
    main_ec2_group_az1 = {
      az                    = "az-1"
      instance_count        = 1
      extra_security_groups = []
      root_volume_size      = 200
      extra_tags            = {}
      management_allow_list = {}
    }
    main_ec2_group_az2 = {
      az                    = "az-2"
      instance_count        = 1
      extra_security_groups = []
      root_volume_size      = 200
      extra_tags            = {}
      management_allow_list = {}
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using a simple `for` expression:

```
locals {
  availability_zones = ["az-1", "az-2"]

  ec2_groups = {
    for az in local.availability_zones : "main_ec2_group_${az}" => {
      az                    = az
      instance_count        = 1
      extra_security_groups = []
      root_volume_size      = 200
      extra_tags            = {}
      management_allow_list = {}
    }
  }
}
```

This produces:

```
  + ec2_groups = {
      + main_ec2_group_az-1 = {
          + az                    = "az-1"
          + extra_security_groups = []
          + extra_tags            = {}
          + instance_count        = 1
          + management_allow_list = {}
          + root_volume_size      = 200
        }
      + main_ec2_group_az-2 = {
          + az                    = "az-2"
          + extra_security_groups = []
          + extra_tags            = {}
          + instance_count        = 1
          + management_allow_list = {}
          + root_volume_size      = 200
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/setproduct to generate a list of instances, mapped to az's.